# How to return a Promise object from a nested Promise function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird, request-promise

I'm having a hard time understanding how Promises work. At the base, I understand what `resolve`, `reject` and `.catch ()` are.

However, I am trying to create a Promise function (using [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html)) that itself uses another Promise function and I want to return a resolve or reject from this nested Promise function. So I have done the following:

**FacebookMessengerAPI.js**

```
const request = require("request-promise");
const Prom = require("bluebird");

exports.send = (sender_psid, response) => {

    return Prom.try(() => {
        if (sender_psid == null || sender_psid == undefined || sender_psid == "") {
            console.error("Invalid sender_psid: \t" + sender_psid);
            let error = {
                code : errorCodes.ERR_INVALID_PARAMETER,
                message : "Invalid sender_psid value"
            }
            return Prom.reject(error); // This works fine
        }

        if (response == null || response == undefined) {
            console.error("Response body is either null or undefined:\t" + response);
            let error = {
                code : errorCodes.ERR_INVALID_PARAMETER,
                message : "Response is either null or undefined"
            }
            return Prom.reject(error); // This also works fine
        }

        let options = {
            url : appConstants.URL_FACEBOOK_GRAPH_API,
            qs : { access_token : appConstants.TOKEN_PAGE_ACCESS },
            method : "POST",
            body : response,
            json : true
        };

        request(options)
            .then((responseBody) => {
                console.log("ResponseBody: \t" + responseBody);
            }, (rejected) => {
                if (rejected.error.error.message) {
                    let error = {
                        code : errorCodes.ERR_FB_GRAPH_API,
                        message : rejected.error.error.message
                    }
                    throw error; // This is where things go wrong
                }
                
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error("Error while calling FB Graph API:\n" + err);
                let error = {
                    code : errorCodes.ERR_UNMAPPED_ERROR,
                    message : err
                };
            });
    });

}
```

**TestApp.js** -- the guy that calls this API

```
"use strict";

const facebookMessengerApi = require("./service/FacebookMessengerApi");

facebookMessengerApi.send(1111,1111).then((resolved) => {
    if (resolved) {
        console.log("Resolves ==> ",resolved);
    }
}, (rejected) => {
    if (rejected) {
        console.log("Rejected:\t" + someshit);
        throw new Error("An err thrown here")
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error("ERRORIFIED:\n\n" + error);
});
```

The problem here is, I don't know how to send a Promise object to the parent Promise function from the `request` function that itself is a Promise function and is nested inside the parent Promise function.

On resolve / reject of the **request** function:

1. When I throw the error by `throw new error`, it is caught in the immediate `.catch` block of the `request` function. It never goes to the actual caller of this API
2. When I use `Prom.reject(error)`, I get `unhandled rejection` warning although I don't know exactly where I'm not handling it since I have handled it both in the `request` method as well as in the caller of this API. Along with that, the `Prom.reject(error)` actually ends up in the `.catch()` block of the `request` function and not in that of the caller function.

Comment: Why do you need the `intermediate` catch if it will bubble anyway to the `request` catch?

Answer (score 1):

### Notes:

- You're doing a throw in your rejection, by definition that's a Promise failure (*ie. another rejection*)
- When you do a `.catch()` on a Promise chain, it recovers the chain

  - This means after a catch, the next `.then()` in the current or parent chain, will now get whatever was returned from the catch statement.
  - Because of this you should either:

    - Run catch at the very end, so there is no more processing done after it
    - And/or ricochet the exception, by thowing / rejecting again, till the next catch statement is triggered
- Promises behave differently depending on what is returned:

  - `<Promise>`: Wait till complete, use value in the next `.then()` in the chain
  - `Not a promise`: Use the return value as the input for the next `.then()`
  - `<Exception>`: Not really a return, but will cause it to go to the next `catch(e)`, where `e` is the exception message
  - `<Rejection>`: Comes from a sub-chain having a rejection, or `Promise.reject(e)` as a return value. Continue to the next `.catch(e)`

**TL;DR -** The output of `.then` / `.catch` will always be the output for the next `.then()` unless there is an exception or rejection in them. In which case the next `.catch()` will be triggered

### Solution / Refactor

```js
// Using standard promises
const prBody = _ => {
    if (sender_psid == null || sender_psid == undefined || sender_psid == "") {
        console.error("Invalid sender_psid: \t" + sender_psid);
        let error = {
            code : errorCodes.ERR_INVALID_PARAMETER,
            message : "Invalid sender_psid value"
        }
        throw error
    }

    if (response == null || response == undefined) {
        console.error("Response body is either null or undefined:\t" + response);
        let error = {
            code : errorCodes.ERR_INVALID_PARAMETER,
            message : "Response is either null or undefined"
        }
        throw error // This also works fine
    }

    let options = {
        url : appConstants.URL_FACEBOOK_GRAPH_API,
        qs : { access_token : appConstants.TOKEN_PAGE_ACCESS },
        method : "POST",
        body : response,
        json : true
    };
    
    // Return a promise which needs to then be resolved for the next thing in the chain to get the data
    return request(options)
        .then(responseBody => {
            console.log("ResponseBody: \t" + responseBody)
            return responseBody
        })
        .catch(errorObj => {
            if (!errorObj.error.error.message) return
            let error = {
                code : errorCodes.ERR_FB_GRAPH_API,
                message : rejected.error.error.message
            }
            throw error; // This is where things go wrong
        })
        // This is going to be the exception you triggered in the previous catch block
        .catch(err => {
            console.error("Error while calling FB Graph API:\n" + err);
            let error = {
                code : errorCodes.ERR_UNMAPPED_ERROR,
                message : err
            };
        });
})
return Promise.resolve()
    .then(prBody)
    .then(responseBodyORError => {
        if (responseBodyORError.error) {return console.log('There was an error, catch simply recover chains')}
        // At this point responseBodyORError will only be the response body, since error checking is done
    })
```